# How can I use "type" as a structure attribute in Go?

Tags: go

"type" is a language keyword but I need to use it as an attribute name in my structure like :

```
type Message struct{
    type string
}
```

My IDE finds an error line 2

Comment: Why do you need to use it ? If you're unmarshalling JSON/Yaml, maybe you could look at the tags. Name your field something else, and simply add some struct tag next to it like ` `json:"type"` `

Comment: I am rewriting an application from another language to GO. Serialized objects need to have same field names. I will use `json` struct tag so. No other solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need to use `type`?

When you need to parse JSON-encoded data with this attribute, you can write the following:

```
type Message struct {
  Kind string `json:"type"`
}
```

Comment: why not ? actually , it is for a json serialized object so i can do it like you say.

Answer (score 6):

`type` is a [keyword](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Keywords) in Go, so you can't use it as an identifier. As an alternative, you can use:

- exported `Type`
- `type_`
- `typ`

All of these I got from the Go source code.

Answer (score 2):

`type` is a reserved word and may not be used as identifiers.
[Docs](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Keywords)